# How to remain Combobox focused while typing in it in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

**Scenario**

I have a combobox named `customerGroup` whereby once there is a change some other routines will be called.

**Codes**

```
Private Sub customerGroup_Change()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call populateDependentCombobox    
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Problem**

When I type in this combobox (Instead of scrolling through the list by mouse), its focus changing to the workbook before I actually get correct value. Because of this, part of the typing happening directly on the workbook

Is there any way whereby I can keep the focus on the combobox itself? I tried the following way. But it is not working

```
Private Sub customerGroup_Change()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    customerGroup.SetFocus
    Call populateDependentCombobox 
    customerGroup.SetFocus   
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If your combobox is in a userform, have you tried `AfterUpdate`? If the combobox in on a worksheet, have you tried `gotfocus and lostfocus`?

Comment: Thank you @GMalc. `AfterUpdate` works fine for my case.

Comment: You are welcome